# Scale across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, scale

I have a data frame with 160 columns and >30k rows.  I would like to scale the values in each column but the trick is that each column belongs to one of three groups and the scaling should happen across all values of each of the three groups.

Here is an example:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(apple.fruit=1:3, dog.pet=1:3, pear.fruit=10001:10003, cat.pet=11:13))
```

Which produces a data frame that looks like this:

```
apple.fruit    dog.pet    pear.fruit    cat.pet
          1          1         10001         11
          2          2         10002         12
          3          3         10003         13
```

What I am hoping for is a clever way to find all columns that have the word "fruit" and scale all of the fruit values collectively across all columns (and do the same for "pet") and end up with this:

```
apple.fruit    dog.pet    pear.fruit    cat.pet
   -0.91305   -1.08112      0.91268     0.72075
   -0.91287   -0.90093      0.91287     0.90093
   -0.91268   -0.72075      0.91305     1.08112
```

---

Said another way: rather than, for apple.fruit to be scaled in this way:

```
scale(data$apple.fruit)
```

I am looking to scale it in this way

```
scale(c(data$apple.fruit, data$pear.fruit))[1:3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your data into long format and scale it one column at a time. Here's a method using `data.table::melt`, which is convenient for letting you melt multiple columns simultaneously based on naming patterns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
roots = unique(sub(".*\\.", "", names(data)))
result = melt(data, measure.vars = patterns(roots))
setnames(result, old = paste0("value", 1:length(roots)), new = roots)
for (j in names(result)[-1]) set(result, j = j, value = scale(result[[j]]))
result
#    variable      fruit        pet
# 1:        1 -0.9130535 -1.0811250
# 2:        1 -0.9128709 -0.9009375
# 3:        1 -0.9126883 -0.7207500
# 4:        2  0.9126883  0.7207500
# 5:        2  0.9128709  0.9009375
# 6:        2  0.9130535  1.0811250
```

---

Otherwise, I think a `for` loop is pretty straightforward:

```
data = as.data.frame(data) # in case you converted to data.table  above
roots = unique(sub(".*\\.", "", names(data)))

for (suffix in roots) {
  cols = grep(paste0(suffix, "$"), names(data))
  data[cols] = scale(unlist(data[cols]))
}
#   apple.fruit    dog.pet pear.fruit   cat.pet
# 1  -0.9130535 -1.0811250  0.9126883 0.7207500
# 2  -0.9128709 -0.9009375  0.9128709 0.9009375
# 3  -0.9126883 -0.7207500  0.9130535 1.0811250
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse way: transform your data in the "long" tidy format, group it by fruit/pet etc, then scale by group

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(cbind(apple.fruit=1:3, dog.pet=1:3, pear.fruit=10001:10003, cat.pet=11:13))
data.tidy <- data %>%
  gather(key="id",value = "value") %>%
  mutate(type = gsub(".*\\.(.*$)","\\1",id),
         name = gsub("(.*)\\..*$","\\1",id)) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(scaleit = scale(value))

data.tidy
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   type [2]
#>    id          value type  name  scaleit
#>    <chr>       <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 apple.fruit     1 fruit apple  -0.913
#>  2 apple.fruit     2 fruit apple  -0.913
#>  3 apple.fruit     3 fruit apple  -0.913
#>  4 dog.pet         1 pet   dog    -1.08 
#>  5 dog.pet         2 pet   dog    -0.901
#>  6 dog.pet         3 pet   dog    -0.721
#>  7 pear.fruit  10001 fruit pear    0.913
#>  8 pear.fruit  10002 fruit pear    0.913
#>  9 pear.fruit  10003 fruit pear    0.913
#> 10 cat.pet        11 pet   cat     0.721
#> 11 cat.pet        12 pet   cat     0.901
#> 12 cat.pet        13 pet   cat     1.08
```

Created on 2018-08-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: The last thing to do, you can return `data.tidy` back to the original dataset using `spread(id, scaleit)`

Comment: Loool, but OP requires a wide format, not long format.